# Calculate length of continuous gaps

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, null

So, I have a list with some nan values, out of which some are continuous. e.g, list = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan, 9, np.nan,np.nan,np.nan, 12] For some necessary reason, I'd want to get the length of individual continuous gaps.

```
def find_continuous_gaps(data):
    gap_starts = []
    gap_lengths = []
    current_gap_start = np.nan
    for i, value in enumerate(data):
        if value is np.nan:
            if current_gap_start is np.nan:
                current_gap_start = i
        else:
            if current_gap_start is not np.nan:
                gap_starts.append(current_gap_start)
                gap_lengths.append(i - current_gap_start)
                current_gap_start = np.nan
    
    if current_gap_start is not np.nan:
        gap_starts.append(current_gap_start)
        gap_lengths.append(len(data) - current_gap_start)
    
    return gap_starts, gap_lengths


# Example usage
data = [1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12]
gap_starts, gap_lengths = find_continuous_gaps(data)
gap_sum = sum_individual_gaps(gap_lengths)

print("Gap starts:", gap_starts)
print("Gap lengths:", gap_lengths)
print("Sum of individual gaps:", gap_sum)

results:

Gap starts: [3, 7, 9]

Gap lengths: [2, 1, 3]

Sum of individual gaps: 6
```

Although it does the job, is there an elegant simpler way for this. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're already using Numpy, but unfortunately you aren't using it as intended. Either this was a shortcut to get a NaN (which, in a program that doesn't otherwise use Numpy, should be done via `float('nan')`); or you need to delete all of your code and vectorise. For small input the benefit is dubious; for large input this will probably be faster.

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([1, 2, 3, np.nan, np.nan, 6, 7, np.nan, 9, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 12])
is_nan = np.isnan(data)
differential = np.diff(is_nan.astype(int))

is_gap_start = differential == 1
is_gap_end = differential == -1
gap_starts = 1 + is_gap_start.nonzero()[0]
gap_ends = 1 + is_gap_end.nonzero()[0]
gap_lengths = gap_ends - gap_starts
gap_sum = is_nan.sum()
```

Answer (score 0):

A function should do only one thing, and do it well. Your function does two things and this does not sound right. This adds complexity and it cannot be justified on performance grounds either.

Python already has some functions that can help you achieve the intended objective. For example: `itertools.groupby`.

From the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby):

> Make an iterator that returns consecutive keys and groups from the
> iterable

Accordingly, this example code:

```
from itertools import groupby

for key, group in groupby(data):
    occurrences = list(group)
    print(f"key: {key} - length: {len(occurrences)} - occurrences: {occurrences}")
```

will produce:

```
key: 1 - length: 1 - occurrences: [1]
key: 2 - length: 1 - occurrences: [2]
key: 3 - length: 1 - occurrences: [3]
key: nan - length: 2 - occurrences: [nan, nan]
key: 6 - length: 1 - occurrences: [6]
key: 7 - length: 1 - occurrences: [7]
key: nan - length: 1 - occurrences: [nan]
key: 9 - length: 1 - occurrences: [9]
key: nan - length: 3 - occurrences: [nan, nan, nan]
key: 12 - length: 1 - occurrences: [12]
```

Now based on this visual example it is trivial to compute `gap_lengths` and this can be done using a **list comprehension**:

```
gap_lengths = [len(list(occurrences)) for key, occurrences in groupby(data) if key is np.nan]
```

As for computing `gap_starts`, this is hardly more difficult. All the legwork has been done and I will leave it to you as an exercise.

I am sure there is more than one way to achieve the same result. I suggested itertools because I'm not too familiar with Numpy, but I would definitely have a look at the Numpy documentation for a suitable function, which may or may not already exist.

Comment: thanks for the new idea to implement itertools. As you said u aren't familiar with numpy, I'm not personally used to itertools. However, going through the above code, it was a better way to do what I wanted. thanks

Answer (score 0):

`NaN`s are on the tricky side.
There's more than one of them.
Rather than `if value is np.nan`,
[prefer](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.isnan.html)

```
        if np.isnan(value):
```

---

Certainly this works:

```
    current_gap_start = np.nan
```

Pythonic code would typically use this customary sentinel:

```
    current_gap_start = None
```

---

It appears `sum_individual_gaps()` is simply the builtin `sum()`.

---

Having assigned `missing = np.array(list(map(np.isnan, data)))`,
we could then find the beginning of each gap with

```
   missing[1:] & ~missing[:-1]
```

---

```
    return gap_starts, gap_lengths
```

A list of [namedtuple](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple)
would be more convenient than coordinating this pair of lists.
Returning a `list` of `range` objects would be
even better, since everyone knows that `gap.stop`
is "exclusive".  Access the other element with `gap.start`.
Smallest change would be:

```
    return [range(start, length + 1)
            for start, length in zip(gap_starts, gap_lengths)]
```

but it would make sense to replace both in the code above, as well.

---

We have some logic repeated, in the loop and at end,
since we wouldn't want to miss dealing with the final gap.

Consider starting with `data = data + [0]`
before the loop.
Tacking on that dummy value lets us remove
the duplicated logic at end.

---

This code achieves its design goals.

I would be willing to delegate or accept maintenance tasks on it.

Comment: thanks @J_H The idea of tacking dummy value was cool. appreciated.